# How to avoid script termination because of subprocess non-zero return code in python?

Tags: python

My Script always terminates abruptly because the command I'm executing using `subprocess.check_call()` or `subprocess.check_output()`

This is the Error.

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\info.exe','-student', 'Tony']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

How do I avoid abnormal termination of the Script in such cases ? I've tried piping the Error/Exception to STDOUT but that didn't seem to help.

```
op = subprocess.check_output([installpath+'\\info.exe','-student', name],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I did read that using `subprocess.call()`. I'm not sure if subprocess.call() is inferior to `subprocess.check_output()` & `subprocess.check_call()`

Comment: just catch this exception.

Comment: The whole point of the `check_xxx` functions is to raise an exception when something goes wrong. Either catch the exception or use a non-`check` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    # start a subprocess
except CalledProcessError:
    # do something if it fails.
```

Comment: This seems like the logical think to do , but what if I just want it to continue executing from where it left off in the "try" block ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar then there is no reason for you to use `check` functions. The only reason to use `subprocess.check_...` is to catch a problem and define some special way to treat them.

Comment: :) okay then call() is what I'm looking for